# Capturing the text within an input field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong in this code. I'm simply trying to set the user's input for username and password and store them in their respective variables. 
For some reason the variables are always and empty string.
Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

HTML

```
<body>
<main>
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <form>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
        <button id="submitButton" type="button">Submit</button>
    </form>
</main>
<script src="loginPage.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var user = {username, password};
console.log(user);
```

Comment: when do you call that javascript code? once the page is loaded? or everything there is a change in the input?

Comment: _set the user's input_ vs. _store them in their respective variables_ || So do you want set the input's value attribute or are you trying to retrieve the input's value attribute value?

Comment: JS seems correct. Can you show us more of your code please? For example, when you actually try to read the values?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the input's value. So say someone enters "joe" into the username field I want var username to equal "joe".

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. Please show some more of your code, where you use it etc.

Comment: OK. So you need to put your two JS statements into an event handler that listens for the 'change' event on the input. That will solve this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind, that the variables will only be populated after a change to the input.

```js
document.querySelector('input[name:username').addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
  var username = e.target.value;
}

document.querySelector('input[name:password').addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
  var password = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <label for="username">Username:</label>
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
   <label for="password">Password:</label>
   <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
</form>
```